# How to set data-attribute with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am working on mvc 4 and use vs 2012.

In my view, I have a table, I wish that the table row is able to change it's color when a user click on it. I add a data-rowidx attribute in the . when user clicl on a row, the attribte will be read and then change the attribute value to row index + 1.  When I use firefox to debug, I found when I click on the third row, the new value 3 is saved into the attribute(I found it in the debug's html tab), but when I click on the other row, I found the value is not 3, but 1, a initial value. It seems the page reloaded. The following is the code. Thank you.

```
function rowClicked(row) {
    var tableId = "#" + row.getAttribute("data-tableId");
    var nthrow = $(tableId).data("rowidx");
    if (nthrow != 0) {
        $(tableId + " tr:nth-child(" + nthrow.toString() + ")").attr("style", "background-color:#efeeef");
    }
    var idx = $(row).index() + 1;
    $(tableId).attr("data-rowidx", idx.toString());
    $(row).attr("style", "background-color:yellow");
    var txtboxName = "#" + row.getAttribute("data-textboxId");
    $(txtboxName).focus();
}
```

Comment: you can access the data attribute by $(selector).data('textboxID') or $(selector).attr('data-textboxId'). I usually use the second approach.

Comment: I think the problem is that the post is being made. If so (without seeing the rest of your code it's hard to tell), you will need to prevent the click event from submitting, by returning false.

Comment: Can you post a link to a [complete](http://sscce.org/#selfcon) example? It's very likely that the error is not actually in this code snippet.

Comment: I have rowclicked and dblclick jquery function on the row. The previous version has a page wide var nthrow to store the current row index. The problem happened after I move this nthrow to the table's data- attribute.

Comment: I am in the weekend. I cannot access my code.

Comment: Hi, I copied code in [link](http://petershaw9.weebly.com/)

Comment: I put a break point in the controller action, I found after click on the row, the action does not execute. So it seems view doesn't reload. Also in w3school, there is a jquery set attribute example in [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_dom_attr_set). I found after clicking the button in the example, the attribute is changed you can prove that by click the link inside the example, but when you view source, the attribute acturally is not changed.